# Apache Zeppelin Connection refused: connect

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am trying to visualize a dataset from spark in Zeppelin. But even for Hello world Zeppelin is throwing `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect` error.

I have correctly set the `SPARK_HOME` to my spark home in my `zeppelin-env.cmd` as I am using Windows 10.

Here is a screenshot of my Spark interpreter in Zeppelin GUI.

[image]

Here is what I get on the output.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to this but here is what I do in case of this error.
Run a paragraph , go to logs folder. list files in reverse order of modified ( ls -lrt : shell command). Now you have the list of logs that are in order they were modified. Check the latest edited log files .

One of the possible reasons can be the checkpoint exception in the secondary namenode. To do this, stop dfs,  delete your /tmp/hadoop-user/ directory content and hadoop-namenode-directory and hadoop-datanode-directory and format the namenode using the command

> /path-to-hadoop/bin/hadoop fs namenode -format

Now restart your setup.
This usually works for me but you have to look into the log files to detect the exact reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to using the wrong interpreter. Click the cog icon ("interpreter binding"), top right in your notebook. Spark should be top of the list. Or you can add `%spark` as the first line of the paragraph to ensure you are using the spark interpreter. (Or `%spark2` if you are using Spark 2).